# Selecting and sizing fonts on MacOS efficiently

Tags: objective-c, macos, fonts

Combining lots of other examples, I've come up with this generic (for my purposes) function to select and size a font using Objective C on MacOS:

```
NSFont *FitSysFont(NSString *text, int w, int h, WORD flags, CGSize *fontsize) {

    int     i, len;
    NSFont  *fnt;
    CGSize  size;
    NSString *fntName;

    NSMutableDictionary *attribs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSRange strRange = [text rangeOfString:text];
    len = (int)[text length];
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

    i = 8;

    if( flags & ST_FIXED ) {
        if( flags & ST_BOLD ) {
            if( flags & ST_ITALIC ) fntName = @"Courier-BoldOblique";
            else fntName = @"Courier-Bold";
        } else if( flags & ST_ITALIC ) {
            fntName = @"Courier-Oblique";
        } else fntName = @"Courier";
    } else {
        if( flags & ST_SERIF ) {
            if( flags & ST_BOLD ) {
                if( flags & ST_ITALIC ) fntName = @"Times-BoldItalic";
                else fntName = @"Times-Bold";
            } else if( flags & ST_ITALIC ) {
                fntName = @"Times-Italic";
            } else fntName = @"Times";
        } else {
            if( flags & ST_BOLD ) {
                if( flags & ST_ITALIC ) fntName = @"Helvetica-BoldOblique";
                else fntName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
            } else if( flags & ST_ITALIC ) {
                fntName = @"Helvetica-Oblique";
            } else fntName = @"Helvetica";
        }
    }
    do {
        ++i;
        [string beginEditing];
        [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[NSFont fontWithName:fntName size:(CGFloat)i] range:strRange];
        [string endEditing];
        fnt = [NSFont fontWithName:fntName size:i];
        [attribs setObject:fnt forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
        size = [text sizeWithAttributes:attribs];
    } while( len && size.width<w && size.height<h );
    do {
        --i;
        [string beginEditing];
        [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[NSFont fontWithName:fntName size:(CGFloat)i] range:strRange];
        [string endEditing];
        fnt = [NSFont fontWithName:fntName size:i];
        [attribs setObject:fnt forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
        size = [text sizeWithAttributes:attribs];
    } while( i>4 && (size.width>=w && size.height>=h );

    if( fontsize!=NULL ) {
        fontsize->width = size.width;
        fontsize->height = size.height;
    }
    return fnt;
}
```

It's designed to select a font that has the given characteristics (specified by 'flags' and the 'w' and 'h' arguments) so that the 'text' string will fit within the given width and height rectangle using the returned font.  It does this by successively trying larger and larger fonts until the text becomes too large for the rectangle (either width or height), then scales back down until the text again fits (probably only one "scale down" will happen). ST_FIXED, ST_SERIF, ST_ITALIC, ST_BOLD are #defines that I've specified elsewhere.

My primary question is whether my sequence of NSthisAndThat is right and proper?  (My understanding of dictionaries and attributes, their lifetimes and setting requirements, is still in development...)  Also, does the [string beginEditing]/[String endEditing] need to be within the loops?  Or can those safely be moved outside, with a single pair at the top and bottom of the pair of loops? Or is there an easier way to determine the font-sizing that would avoid the do-loops entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your `string` variable at all. You manipulate its attributes, but you never use the result for anything. Of course, that also means you don't need `strRange`.

The rest looks OK, assuming you're using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). If you're not, you need to release `attribs` (and `string` if you don't eliminate that).

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  Good catch on 'string'.  Yes, using ARC.